# Why differentiate between irrational and transcedental numbers?

Tags: soft-question, transcendental-numbers

As the title says, I am wondering why transcedental numbers ever were introduced. Other common subsets of $\mathbb R$, such as natural numbers, integers rational and irrationals are obvious. For example counting, indicating fractions of integers and for expressing values like the area of a circle.

This gives rise to the question why we ever introduced the transcedental numbers. They are a subset of the irrational numbers, and are defined as numbers that cannot be expressed as the roots of polynomials with integer coefficients, but who cares? (Apologies for the blunt statement) I know these sets are not introduced for fun, but were a necessity at some point, meaning that either irrational numbers were not specific enough, or they were introduced before the irrationals, which seems unlikely to me.

Comment: May as well ask why irrational numbers, since they're "just" the subset of the reals that aren't rational.

Comment: I wonder what motivated this question—you must *really* dislike transcendental numbers! In any case, knowing whether a number is algebraic or transcendental is very important if you're studying field extensions, for example. See also [transcendence degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendence_degree).

Comment: @coffeemath Well I would say that this is for example to indicate that the distinction between rational and irrational numbers is that for example $\pi$, the area of a circle with radius $1$, cannot be expressed as fraction. However, I do not see what would be the added value of saying that the area of a circle cannot be expressed as the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: @User123456789 See Clive's comment above, with its link to transcendence degree.

Comment: @User123456789 Mostly the value of that information is that if $\pi$ really _were_ the root of a polynomial, **that** would be incredible.

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ is an early example of an irrational number, and it's a root of $x^2 -2$. After discovering irrational numbers like $\sqrt{2}$, it becomes natural to wonder if there are any numbers which aren't a root of any polynomial with rational coefficients. So at that point we have already discovered the idea of transcendental numbers but we don't know if any exist, so it's a nice puzzle. If thinking about this idea leads to interesting new math (which it did), then the idea will survive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You're looking at the wrong sets. It's not about differentiating the irrational numbers from the trancendental numbers. It's about differentiating the rational numbers from the algebraic numbers. Both the rational and algebraic numbers are so important that even their complements have special names, and you seem to be focusing on those.

Comment: If I get this right, the focus should be on that for example $\pi$ is $\textit{not}$ algabraic, and not that $\pi$ is transcedental?

Comment: @User123456789 Yes (if those two things can be said to be different at all). It's the same with, say, the irrationality of $\sqrt2$. It is the fact that you _cannot_ write it as a fraction which is important (and which revolutionized the ancient Greek understanding of numbers). Whether you call that fact "$\sqrt 2$ is irrational" or "$\sqrt 2$ is not rational" is up to you, though.